# How to change the axis resolution plotting in R

Tags: r, parameters, plot

I wanted to know if there is a parameter to modify the spacing or the resolution of the axis making a plot in R.

I have a lot of points between 0 and 800, and i want the gaps(space between graph's dots) to be visible, I used the pch="_" But still cant see the gaps easily.

Thanks

Comment: You probably want to set `xaxt='n'` (and/or `yaxt='n'`) in your original plotting call and then manually specify axes using `axis`, which provides much finer control.

Comment: I understood the question to be how to make individual points smaller inside the plot area of a base-graphics plot. If that is correct, then try `cex=0.1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the hint provided by @IShouldBuyABoat, try the `cex` argument:

```
x=seq(0,2,by=0.1)
y=rep.int(1,21)

par(mfrow=c(1,3))

plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,2),cex=0.1) #what you want
plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,2)) #without using cex argument (default value)
plot(x,y,xlim=c(0,2),cex=4) #exaggerating the effect you have
```

[image]

Comment: You could consider the slightly more compact notation: `x = seq(0,2,by=.1)`.